# How to solve - Provisional headers are shown?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

How to solve - Provisional headers are shown?

I have a Django application using rest_framework, simple JWT and corsheaders.

GET request works perfectly, however POST I get a 200 code, but with restrictions. Provisional headers are shown

Authentication works perfectly, however I am having problem in request.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
      'rest_framework',
      'corsheaders',
  ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'lbuser_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It Work.

I urei the request.body instead of the request.POST